# Word/phrase meaning fatal blow (in an argument)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm searching for a word, phrase or term that means the fatal blow, something along the lines of coup de grace.   However, that term has implies a merciful killing.  I'm looking for something that connotes a savagery; a complete evisceration.

For example, you're describing the arguments an attorney is making to a court.  The attorney is *hammering* the adversary.  Then s/he makes this [coup de grace] argument to just drive it home. There's nothing merciful about it (that's why I don't like coup de grace in this context).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the traditional meaning of coup de grace is merciful killing, but I also hear it when it's intended to mean a general final blow or end. Many may consider this usage incorrect, and you can avoid it if you want, but here are a few sources that give this more general meaning:

> 2:a decisive finishing blow, act, or event 
>  The decision to cut
>   funding is the coup de grâce to the governor's proposal.
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coup%20de%20gr%C3%A2ce)
>
> 2.A finishing stroke or decisive event.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coup+de+grace)
>
> 2.a final or decisive stroke
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coup+de+grace)
>
> 2.any finishing or decisive stroke.
>  [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coup+de+grace)
>
> Same definition as above from Random House Unabridged
>   ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/coup-de-grace))

A word or term that's related to coup de grace is "death blow", sometimes given as one word, which has less association with putting out one's misery or mercy killing.

> 1.1An event or circumstance which abruptly ends something.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/death_blow)

You can see a few examples of its use in the last link to see if this is satisfactory to you.

Answer (score 3):

**"deathblow"** (or "death blow") seems like a good fit.

> From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/death-blow) - "If you say that an event or action deals a death blow to something such as a plan or hope, or is a death blow to something, you mean that it puts an end to it."
>
> - The deportations would be a death blow to the peace process.
> - It has been asserted that the theory of evolution dealt a death blow to religious belief.
> - The death blow came after the American government decided not to intervene to save the bank.
>
> From [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/death%20blow)"death blow" or "deathblow" - "an act or event that causes the end or failure of something."

Answer (score 1):

**the final straw**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Final)

> The last in a series of negative actions or events that makes the
>   situation no longer tolerable.

As in:

If you can't be bothered to come with me to my own mother's funeral,
that will be the **final straw**! We are done!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for (if not *coup de grace*—a phrase you say in your question you *don't* want) is **knockout punch** or **knockout blow**.

In dictionaries, it's the word [**knockout**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knockout) that's relevant:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 b(1)** : the termination of a boxing match when one boxer has been knocked down and is unable to rise and resume boxing within a specified time
>
> [Collins]
>
> A **knockout** blow is an action or event that completely defeats an opponent.
>
> *He delivered a knockout blow to all of his rivals.*